# How to safely create software RAID 1 in Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, raid, mdadm

a week ago installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 on laptop as dev server and decided to enable software RAID1 on it. Already put the second hdd into it and decided before going to break something to try this tutorial on a VBox'ed Ubuntu with 2 virtual drives: https://www.prado.lt/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-lvm-system-incl-grub2-configuration-ubuntu-18-04

The problem is that after following it the `fdisk -l` command on the REAL machine shows:

```
root@test:/# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 9.7 MiB, 9510912 bytes, 18576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 97.6 MiB, 101777408 bytes, 198784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 97.72 MiB, 102445056 bytes, 200088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 54.98 MiB, 57626624 bytes, 112552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 55.33 MiB, 58007552 bytes, 113296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 68.73 MiB, 72048640 bytes, 140720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 68.64 MiB, 71962624 bytes, 140552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 30.95 MiB, 32432128 bytes, 63344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST500LM012 HN-M5
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CBE0124B-3C38-41E7-A4F6-A2599D5AE737

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   4096 976771071 976766976 465.8G Linux filesystem


The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdc: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST500LM021-1KJ15
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CBE0124B-3C38-41E7-A4F6-A2599D5AE737

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdc2   4096 976771071 976766976 465.8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/loop8: 30.27 MiB, 31735808 bytes, 61984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


GPT PMBR size mismatch (976773167 != 976508927) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/md0: 465.65 GiB, 499972571136 bytes, 976508928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/md0p1          1 976508927 976508927 465.7G ee GPT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Already did this step:
`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/md0 bs=16K status=progress conv=sync,noerror,notrunc`

Some additional info from the REAL machine:

```
root@test:/# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdc[1]
      488254464 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

root@test:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M  1.9M  383M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       458G   12G  423G   3% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      9.2M  9.2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10126
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop3       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop1       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9993
/dev/loop8       31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9279
/dev/loop7       31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9607
/dev/loop6       69M   69M     0 100% /snap/lxd/17629
/dev/loop5       69M   69M     0 100% /snap/lxd/17738
tmpfs           385M     0  385M   0% /run/user/1000
```

SMART status of drives:

```
root@test:/# smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-48-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M8 (AF)
Device Model:     ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB
Serial Number:    S2ZYJ9EGB02579
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0004cf 21138cf1c
Firmware Version: 2BA30001
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Oct 17 04:36:15 2020 EEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                ( 5880) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  98) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       365
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   095   083   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       1786
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5230
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8095
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       295
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5239
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       123
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       210
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   060   044   000    Old_age   Always       -       40 (Min/Max 14/56)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   252   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       86925
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       295
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   050   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       505339

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Completed [00% left] (0-65535)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

root@test:/# smartctl -a /dev/sdc
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-48-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Laptop HDD
Device Model:     ST500LM021-1KJ152
Serial Number:    W62ANTP8
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 090679a73
Firmware Version: 0002YXM1
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Oct 17 04:37:59 2020 EEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  79) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x103d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   114   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       63743728
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   098   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       757
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   067   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       64515159546
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4048
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       756
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4295622666
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   065   045   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 35 (Min/Max 24/55)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       233
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       14
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       17501
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   035   055   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (0 16 0 0 0)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

What will be the next SAFE command if following the tutorial? Thanks in advance

Comment: SMART data please?

Comment: SMART status of both drives added

Comment: Cheers! Can you force a SMART test - your log shows no SMART self tests executed so  use https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en and click self test...

Comment: sorry - missed the edit window - just checking no change from data posted (which looks ok )

Comment: They already went through that on a Desktop machine and are OK

Comment: ignoring /dev/loop*, you have sda, sdc and a software md0 which implies a missing sdb. How are you configuring md0 (not an expert but I have  2x working machines with md raid) your partition tables and physical discs would be really helpful (others may be better placed than me to contribute with this information)

Comment: Yeah, `/dev/sdb` is the generic sd-card reader. Configured it using the tutorial from the link except LVM-specific commands

Answer (score 1):

Learning from others mistakes:

> *Start from scratch*

Did everything again, but following this tutorial (note that Ubuntu's semantics is a bit weird when talking about the correct sequence of steps in their documentation):

[Install Ubuntu 18.04 on RAID1 by Calvin.Me](https://calvin.me/install-ubuntu-18.04-on-raid1)

It's working like a charm